# Contest math factoring polynomials, issue with solution set?

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

I have been working on some practice problems involving polynomials and came across this one.

> Let $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a monic degree $n$ polynomial. Suppose there exists four distinct integers $a,b,c,d$ such that $p(a) = p(b) = p(c) = p(d) = 5$. Prove that there is no integer $k$ such that $p(k) = 8$.

I believe this is false, take $a=1, b=3, c=-1, d=5$. Then $p(x) = (x+1)(x-1)(x-3)(x-5)g(x) + 5$ evaluates to $8$ at $k = 2$ is $g(2) = 1/3$. I see no reason why this cannot be the case since we do not assume $g(x)$ has integer coefficients.

The solution given is the following:

> We have that $a,b,c,d$ are distinct roots of $P(x)-5$, hence $P(x)−5 = g(x)(x−a)(x−b)(x−c)(x−d)$, where $g(x)$ is a polynomial with integral coefficients. If $P(k) = 8$ then $g(x)(x−a)(x−b)(x−c)(x−d) = 3$,but $3$ is a prime number, so all the factors on the left but one must be $\pm 1$. So among the numbers $(x−a), (x−b), (x−c), (x−b)$, there are either two $1$’s or two $−1$’s, which implies that $a,b,c,d$ cannot be all distinct, a contradiction.

I don't see why all of them but $1$ have to be $\pm 1$, can't two of the factors be $\pm 3$ and the other two be $\pm 1$, and $g(x)$ be whatever makes it work?

Comment: For example $x^2-2$ factors but not with integer coefficients, so I was and still am unconvinced that $g$ must have integer coefficients. Regardless, the problem would not be solved if it did, since then we can supposed $g$ evaluates $\pm 1$. There is no issue there, at least not one that immediately gives a solution. We can still have $(x-i)$ distinct for $i=a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Also, $g$ must be monic, sure, but the other coefficients need not be integral as far as I can tell.

Comment: I see your point, no need to be passive-aggressive. So we agree that $g$ has integer coefficients. Then $g(k)$ is integral for all integers $k$ and so it must be $\pm1$ or $\pm3$ for the divisors on both sides to be the same, but must be $1/3$ for the equality to work out and we get a contradiction. Is this correct? It also still seems that the solution set is incorrect, am I missing anything else?

Comment: Is it $p(k)=k$ or $p(k)=8$??

Comment: As far as I can see, the solution that you post only proves that $p(3)\ne 3$ $-$ it doesn't prove that for all integers $k$, $p(k)\ne k$. Did you only post part of the solution?

Comment: I had a typo, it should have been $p(k) = 8$ as noted by Anas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can't have $g(2)=1/3$ while $P(x)$ is with integer coefficients. Let $g(x)=(x-2)h(x)+1/3$ and then when you multiply you may get non-integer coefficients. This is not a rigorous proof, I can't proof it completely, but you may try different $g$ and you'll get that it can't be. So, instead of proving or trying to find $g$ where it might not be the case, stick to what's given in the problem. So, let's all agree that also $g$ has to have integral coefficients.

Now regarding the solution,
$$P(k)=8 \implies g(k)(k-a)(k-b)(k-c)(k-d)=3$$
Let's examine the possibilities:

1. One of the factors is $-3$ and three of them are $-1$ and one of them is $1$. Since $3$ of them are $-1$ then there are at least $2$ of $(k-a), \ (k-b), \ (k-c), \ (k-d)$ equal $-1$, in which case $2$ of them are not distinct.
2. One of the factors is $-3$ and three of them are $1$ and one of them is $-1$. Since $3$ of them are $1$ then there are at least $2$ of $(k-a), \ (k-b), \ (k-c), \ (k-d)$ equal $1$, in which case $2$ of them are not distinct.
3. One of the factors is $3$, and two from the other four are $-1$ and the other two are $1$. This directly leads that two of them are not distinct.

So, there you have it!